# TypeScript: declare a variable that is a function named "new"

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I want to write TypeScript definitions of a modules where it's JavaScript equivalent is the following:

```
var service = {};
service.new = function (name, options) {
    console.log('Ive been called!');
};
module.exports = service;
```

How shall I declare it? I can't find a way to declare this property called new on the service as new is a reserved keyword but still this JavaScript code works and should be definable in a .d.ts file.

My last failed attempt was

```
export = ModuleName;
export as namespace ModuleName;

declare var instance: ModuleName.StaticInstance;

declare namespace ModuleName {

    interface StaticInstance {
        new(name: string, options: ModuleName.Options): NewService;
    }

    interface NewService {
        someMethod()...
    }

    interface Options {
        option1: number;
        ...
    }
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Because you add `new` as a property to an object, if you try to declare a variable with that name, you will get an error, property name `!==` identifier, reserved keywords only put restriction on identifiers, not property names

Comment: The error I was getting with this attempt was that the property "new" does not exists on StaticInstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain contexts you can quote identifier names:

```
interface MyModule {
    "new"(name: string, options: Options): NewService;
}

declare const m: MyModule;
export = m;
```

Comment: Funny I was pretty sure to have tried something like that but apparently I did it wrong as it works! Thanks!