# Typescript: Declaring a function with a keyword for name

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a typescript declaration file, and one of the functions is called 'export', as shown below.

```
declare namespace DocumentPicker {
    function export(path: string): Promise<[string]>;
}
```

When trying to declare it, I get the error below, saying that 'an identifer is expected'.

```
src/index.d.ts:213:14 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.

213     function export (path: string): Promise<[string]>;
                 ~~~~~~
```

A [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597861/typescript-declare-a-variable-that-is-a-function-named-new) suggested putting quotes around the function name, but that didn't work either. How would I declare this method? Thanks

Comment: I think `export` is a reserved keyword (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536), can you name it something else?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can. It's someone else's library, but I'll see if I can get them to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible within a namespace. But if you declare `DocumentPicker` as an object, there's no problem at all. There is no restriction on object property names or methods (they can even be computed, but it's not necessary here)

```
declare const DocumentPicker: {
    export(path: string): Promise<[string]>;
}
```