# Map and filter an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, filter

I’m trying to map a nested array and return the words that have more letters than 6, I have been stuck for a while with this problem so I’d like to get some help

```
const array = [["hellow",'pastas'],["travel", "militarie"],["oranges","mint"]]

  const arrayOne = array.map(new => new).filter(arr =>arr.length > 6)
```

Comment: 1) `new` is a reserved keyword 2) Please post the code with single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) and not `“` 3) What is the expected output?

Comment: Why are you insisting on using `.map()` and `.filter()`? Doesn't seem like the right tool for this job.

Comment: Using `map()/filter()/reduce()` would make a little more sense. `array.map(a => a.filter(s => s.length > 6)).reduce((acc, a) => acc.concat(a), [])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: declare a variable that is a function named "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597861/typescript-declare-a-variable-that-is-a-function-named-new)

Answer (score 0):

You can `flat` array first and than `filter` out words with length greater than `6`

```js
const array = [['hellow','pastas'],['travel', 'militaries'],['oranges','mint']]

const arrayOne = array.flat(1).filter(e=> e.length > 6 )

console.log(arrayOne)
```

Comment: I need to use map and not flat

Comment: @Prisme but why ? in this case `map` is not suitable

Answer (score 0):

I think better will be the filter() method instead.

```
array.filter(function (c) {
    return c.length < 6;
});
```

But first use the flat() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. This code uses `.map()` and `.filter()` to check if the length is greater than 6, and adds it to the array if it is.

```js
const array = [["hellow","pastas"],["travel", "militarie"],["oranges","mint"]];
const arrayOne = array.map(e1 => e1.filter(e2 => e2.length > 6)).flat();

console.log(arrayOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const array = [['hellow','pastas'],['travel', 'militarie'],['oranges','mint']];

const result = array.flatMap(x => x.filter(y => y.length > 6));

console.log(result);
```

Another way is to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const array = [['hellow','pastas'],['travel', 'militarie'],['oranges','mint']];

const result = array.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, ...x.filter(y => y.length > 6)], []);

console.log(result);
```